# Apex Test class question

Tags: apex

Can a test class be used to test multiple classes? 
For example: a parent object and child object get have classes that get called via triggers, would it be possible to validate them with one large test class?

(for the record its still bad form to do if it is possible)

Comment: @sfdcfox gave a good answer to this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73531/test-classes-to-cover-multiple-triggers-classes-or-1-to-1

Comment: That link provides an excellent use case as to how this could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.  In theory, a single test class could test all of the functionality in your org (it could take several testmethods to do that though)

You'll see lots of example where there is class `Foo` and corresponding test class `FooTest`.  But, there certainly are situations where you are testing end-end functionality by exercising some user action (save of a record, click of a button, ...) where many classes will get executed to complete the transaction.

Regardless, whatever you do, be sure to add `system.assert(..)` methods to verify actual results and avoid `seeAllData=true` test annotation.  `75% Code coverage != good testing` .

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you can. Whether it is bad form depends on your use case.

I would never use one class to test an entire system, but if the code being tested is functionally similar and **it makes sense**, then go for it.

If you end up using different classes, you can always leverage the `@TestSetup` clause to create all your data in one of the classes before the tests run. From the other class, in its own `@TestSetup` method, you can call the first class's.